laravel livewire 3 dom rerender select2 search is disappear
I'm using Laravel Livewire 3 with Dependent Select  options Like, Country, State, City using Select 2 with search on Select options, After select country select2 search is disappear.
When I select Country select2 on country search is disappear,  same city, state as well.
Blade.php
<div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="ps-checkout__group">
            <label class="ps-checkout__label">Country *</label>
            <select wire:model.live="bSelectedCountry" name="bCountry" class="form-control input-dropdown bCountry">
                <option value="">Select a country</option>
                @foreach(App\Models\SysCountry::where('status', 1)->get() as $item)
                    <option value="{{$item->id}}" >{{$item->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="ps-checkout__group">
            <label class="ps-checkout__label">State *</label>
            <select wire:model.live="billingStateId" class="form-control input-dropdown bState" >
                <option value="">Select a State</option>
                @foreach($billingStateList as $item)
                    <option value="{{$item->id}}" >{{$item->name}}</option>
                @endforeach

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.bCountry').select2();
            $('.bCountry').on('change', function() {
                let data = $(this).val();
                @this.set('bSelectedCountry', data);
            });

            //## State
            $('.bState').select2();
            $('.bState').on('change', function() {
                let data = $(this).val();
            @this.set('billingStateId', data);
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush


Livewire Component
public $billingStateList, $billingCityList;  

public function updatedbSelectedCountry($id){
    $this->billingStateList = SysState::where(['country_id' => $id])->get();
}
public function updatedBillingStateId($id){
    $this->billingCityList = SysCity::where(['state_id' => $id])->get();
}


Since the secondary select depends on the parent one, it must be updated dynamically. This leads to a conflict between the management of Livewire and that of Select2 which overlap in the modification of the DOM. I therefore decided to remove the management of the selects from Livewire and still have it read the data from the storage.
The view
<div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

        <div class="ps-checkout__group">

            <label class="ps-checkout__label">Country *</label>

            <span wire:ignore>

                <select class="form-control input-dropdown bCountry">
                    <option value="">Select a country</option>
                    <!-- the options will be loaded by JS -->
                </select>

            </span>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

        <div class="ps-checkout__group">

            <label class="ps-checkout__label">State *</label>

            <span wire:ignore>

                <select class="form-control input-dropdown bState">
                    <!-- the options will be loaded by JS -->
                </select>

            </span>

        </div>

    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div> <!-- this is for debugging -->

        Country: [{{ $bSelectedCountry }}]
        <br>
        State: [{{ $bSelectedState }}]

    </div>

</div>

@push('scripts')

    <script>

        $(function () {

            // The countries are converted in JSON data to be managed by JS
            const countries = {{ Js::from($countries) }};

            $(".bCountry").select2({data: countries})

                          .on("change", async (el) => {

                              // assigns the value of the select to the property of the class
                              @this.bSelectedCountry = el.target.value;

                              // reset of the secondary select
                              @this.bSelectedState = null;

                              // request for rows to the backend - due to this call the view is updated automatically
                              const statesList = await @this.stateList();

                              // update of the child select   
                              initStates (statesList);
                          });
          
            // initial setup of the child select
            initStates();

        });


        function initStates (data = {}) {

            const stateSelect = $(".bState");

            if (stateSelect.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible"))
                stateSelect.select2("destroy");

            stateSelect.empty()
                       .append('<option value="">Select a State</option>')
                       .select2({data: data})
                       .off("change")
                       .on("change", (el) => {
                            // assigns the value of the select to the property of the class  
                            @this.bSelectedState = el.target.value;

                            // this replaces the .live modifier
                            @this.$refresh();
                       });
        }

    </script>

@endpush

Each select is wrapped by a span that contains a wire:ignore to prevent Livewire from updating. This means that the options and the interactions must be managed via Javascript.
I've also added the ouptut of the selected values for debugging.
The class
class TestSelect extends Component
{
    public $billingCountriesList;
    public $billingStatesList;
    public $bSelectedCountry = null;
    public $bSelectedState = null;

    
    public function updatedbSelectedCountry($id) {
        $this->billingStateList = SysState::where(['country_id' => $id])->get();
    }


    public function updatedBillingStateId($id) {
        $this->billingCityList = SysCity::where(['country_id' => $id])->get();
    }
   

    public function stateList() {

        return SysStates::where('status', 1)
                         ->ordeBy('name')
                         ->get(['id', 'name as text'])  // Select2 accepts id - text
                         ->toArray();
    }


    public function render() {

        // the countries for the main select are passed from the backend
        $countries = SysCountries::where('status', 1)
                                 ->ordeBy('name')
                                 ->get(['id', 'name as text'])  // Select2 accepts id - text
                                 ->toArray();

        return view('livewire.test-select', ['countries' => $countries]);
    }


I moved to the class side the reading of the options of the main select, it
is always advisable to keep the data selection in the backend and moreover in this case some manipulations are necessary
